# CORS Response Header “Set-Cookie” could not be retrieved

Tags: cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-pages

I’ve setup the react UI in Cloudflare Pages with custom domain `https://ui.example.com`. There is a login page that allows users to key in user name and password. Once they’ve supplied the info, it will use axios to make a call to an API that is hosted in Cloudflare Workers `https://apis.example.com` and from there I’ve written sample codes to return Set-Cookies header with the “secret-token” value.

Since Pages and Workers reside in different domain, so I’ve configured Workers to supplied the following values to the API response, in addition to Set-Cookies header-values:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*"
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
"Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "Set-Cookie"
```

But when I check the response headers by using script (console.log) written in my login.jsx, it only contains content-length and content-type. But when I check the response from Chrome (Developer Tools’ Network) in my case, those header-values above exist.

How can I get the response’s header values from the axios call in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a different header name.

`Set-Cookie` is a [forbidden response header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name), which means JavaScript is not permitted to read this header. The browser handles this header (adding the cookie to cookie storage) and then *removes it* before JavaScript sees the response at all.

Instead, try inventing your own header name, like `X-Secret-Token`.